# how can I edit "user_mobile" value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I want to edit "user_mobile" and "user_blood".

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pljf.png]

I have Tried this code.

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String online_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        getUserDataReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(online_user_id);

getUserDataReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //dataSnapshot.get

                String name = dataSnapshot.child("user_name").getValue().toString();
                String status = dataSnapshot.child("user_status").getValue().toString();
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("user_image").getValue().toString();
                mobile = dataSnapshot.child("user_mobile").getValue().toString();
                String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("user_thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                settingDisplayName.setText(name);
                settingDisplayStatus.setText(status);

                if (!image.equals("default_profile"))
                {
                    Picasso.with(SettingActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_profile).into(settingsDisplayImage);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

**Here is the Error.**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.logictex.bloodbank, PID: 2486
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.logictex.bloodbank.SettingActivity$1.onDataChange(SettingActivity.java:77)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: The child of `Users` in this schema is `AB+`, not `online_user_id`. Hence the NPE. This line: `getUserDataReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(online_user_id);`

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference xyz= 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(online_user_id).child("user_mobile");
xyz.setValue("set_desired vaule");
```

do same for use_blood

Comment: and how can I get these values.

Answer (score 0):

May be your path `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(online_user_id);` doesn't exists.

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   // dataSnapshot is null or it's children are returning null
   // 
   if(dataSnapshot !=null){
      // do your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: and how can I get these values.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

DatabaseReference user_mobileRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(user_blood).child(online_user_id).child("user_mobile");
user_mobileRef.setValue("YourNewValue");

DatabaseReference user_bloodRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(user_blood).child(online_user_id).child("user_blood");
user_bloodRef.setValue("YourNewValue");
```

Comment: AB+ is not hardcore. It changed for other users.

Comment: I understand. Please see my updated answer. I have changed that child with this: `.child(user_blood)`. Does it work?

Comment: and how can I get these values.

Comment: You already have it because i see that `user_blood` fields has a value. In the screen-shot i see that has the value of AB+. So you need to use this particular value in your `DatabaseReference`. All you need to do, is to get down in the three to the desired location and use `setValue()` method.

Comment: Having error onDataChangedMethod. Where getting the values.

Comment: Mate, the error log is not related to the question. You are asking how to edit "user_mobile” value. The response is above. Note, that you don't need to use `addValueEventListener` in order to change a value. This approach is wrong. You must use `setValue()` method directly on the reference.

Comment: I want to get previous value before updating new value.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not possible with this database structure, because you are trying to use a value in the `DatabaseReference` before getting it. You need to change the database structure so you can know all the childs needed to get the desired value.